# trying to create ranked subgraphs in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I've tried to make something like this using Graphviz:

```
    x   y   z
    |   |   |
    #   |   |
   a#__\|   |
    #  /#b  |
    #   #__\|
    #   #  /#c
    #  d#/__#
    #   #\  x
    #   #   |
   e#/__#   |
    #\  #   |
```

But ranking doesn't seem to be working as I expect.  I want `e` to be below all of the other nodes.

```
digraph x
{
  rankdir = tb;
  size = "7.5, 7.5";
  rank = source;
  a -> b -> c -> d -> e;
  subgraph "cluster x"
  {
    style=filled;
    color=lightgrey;
    label="x";
    a -> e [style=invis];
  }
  subgraph "cluster y"
  {
    label="y";
    b -> d [style=invis];
  }
  subgraph "cluster z"
  {
    label="z";
    c;
  }
}
```

[image: First attempt]

I've tried to use `clusterrank = global` which sort of works, but then the subgraphs are not separated into a more obvious column and there's overlap over the columns.  It also is not going to the right like I want.  The following image highlights one of the overlaps in red, but as you can see there are 4.

[image: 2nd attempt]

```
digraph x
{
  rankdir = tb;
  rankstep=equally;
  clusterrank = global;
  size = "7.5, 7.5";
  a -> b -> c -> d -> e;
  subgraph "cluster x"
  {
    style=filled;
    color=lightgrey;
    label="x";
    a -> e [style=invis];
  }
  subgraph "cluster y"
  {
    label="y";
    b -> d [style=invis];
  }
  subgraph "cluster z"
  {
    label="z";
    c;
  }
}
```

I've tried to make a separate cluster that is going to have a guaranteed top to bottom ranking and then rank the appropriate clusters together, but it does the same as the previous attempt, removing the boxes seen the the first attempt and causing unwanted overlapping.

```
digraph x
{
  rankdir = tb;
  1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5;
  a -> b -> c -> d -> e;
  { rank=same; 1; a; }
  { rank=same; 2; b; }
  { rank=same; 3; c; }
  { rank=same; 4; d; }
  { rank=same; 5; e; }

  subgraph "cluster x"
  {
    style=filled;
    color=lightgrey;
    label="x";
    a -> e [style=invis];
  }
  subgraph "cluster y"
  {
    label="y";
    b -> d [style=invis];
  }
  subgraph "cluster z"
  {
    label="z";
    c;
  }
}
```

[image: 3rd attempt]

Anyone have any ideas as to try and get the layout I want?

As a side note, I tried to login to the Graphviz forum regarding this matter, but found that logging in from [this page](http://www.graphviz.org/user/login?destination=Forum) doesn't seem to work.  I keep getting a long timeout problem.  I check my email account and nothing is there.  I try creating a new account with the same email and it says that the account is already in use.  I then try and get them to reset my password and I get another timeout problem.

Does anyone know who I can contact to try and fix that annoying login problem?  Maybe someone who is already logged in can post that for me?

Answer (score 1):

Run dot with -Gnewrank. That will get you what you want based on your sketch. If more tweaks are needed, please specify what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Your last solution will work as soon as you do a minor tuning

Use `newrank=true` to avoid of "unboxing" clusters

Play with `splines=...` to adjust arrows

Define label as separate nodes.

```
digraph x
{
  rankdir = tb;
  newrank=true;
  splines=ortho;

  0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5;
  X; Y; Z;
  a -> b -> c -> d -> e;
  { rank=same; 0 X Y Z}
  { rank=same; 1; a; }
  { rank=same; 2; b; }
  { rank=same; 3; c; }
  { rank=same; 4; d; }
  { rank=same; 5; e; }

  subgraph "cluster x"
  {
    style=filled;
    color=lightgrey;
    a -> e [style=invis];
  }
  subgraph "cluster y"
  {
    b -> d [style=invis];
  }
  subgraph "cluster z"
  {
    c;
  }
}
```

[image]